# Tooltip on area under a plotted line with stacked area chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, plot, flot

I have a stacked area chart (an example is included below) where I would like to have a tooltip with the upper line's nearest point's data appear every time the mouse hovers an area between two lines.

I have absolutely no idea on how to do this and my search queries were unsuccessful into finding a potential solution. I can only make a tooltip on the actual points of the plotted lines but not on the areas between them.

Do you have any idea on how to do it ?

Thank you in advance !

Example of chart : [Example of chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYNLD.png)

Comment: Did you try using image maps in HTML?? You can break up parts of an image into any shape you want and different tooltips can be applied to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Flot example seems to do what you want: http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/interacting.html.

It should be pretty straightforward, based on this code, to use jQuery to add a tooltip at the location of the cursor that displays the point's data. However, you might be better off displaying the coordinates of the cursor (time and value, or whatever) and only using a tooltip for the points provided by your data.